# Password Aging: Script

Tags: linux, nis

We have to implement Password Aging in our environment. I know that it is very much possible using chage and shadow file.
But since our Passwords are handeled by NIS, we can not use chage method in order to implement password ageing. I just wonder
if I can write a script which checks the passwd file periodically(daily) in order to findout who all users have NOT changed
their passwords since lets say 180 Days and I get a mail notification. So that I can inform the users and ask them to change their passwords.
Some sort of Password ageing. I know it will not be a perfect case but we have to go with this workaround.
We only have 55 UNIX Users so far.
Since I am not into programming, I would request you all to provide me some hints as to how to do it.
I have given a try but is not worth it.

```
###Here the script will change the difference in two password files passwd.2 and passwd.11 and if there are differences then record them(only Usernames) in the file Table 
#!/bin/bash
#set -x


if [[ "$(diff passwd.2 passwd.11 )" != "" ]]; then
        ( date ; echo FileChanged ) >> Status2
        ( diff passwd.2 passwd.11 ) >> Status2
        diff --unchanged-line-format="" --old-line-format="" --new-line-format=":%dn: %L" passwd.2 passwd.11  |awk -F: '{print $3}' >> Table
        tail -15 Status2
        tail -15 Table
else
        ( date ; echo NOFileChanged ) >> Status2
fi
```

A sample password file is given below.
passwd:

```
t1:$2y$05$lFZBPdAihnWxJPwfHeoI8WBdhzZGtcVJXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:10954:20000:Test User temporary:/home/t1:/bin/bash
fdl:Nologin*:499:20190:fdl,Application User:/home/fdl:/bin/csh
v1:$2y$05$lPdAihnWXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXcPwfHeoI8WBdhzZGtcVJXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:10955:20000:Test User temporary:/home/v1:/bin/bash
v2:$2y$05BPdAihnWxJeXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXoI8WBdhzZGXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:10956:20000:Test User temporary:/home/v2:/bin/bash
v3:$2y$05$lFZBPdAiXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXoI8WBdhzZGXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:10957:20000:Test User temporary:/home/v3:/bin/bash
v4:$2y$05$lFZBPdAXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXfHeoI8WBdhzXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:10958:20000:Test User temporary:/home/v4:/bin/bash
```

Comment: Why NIS and not something a little better supported like LDAP (or even AD)? If you're starting out then NIS almost certainly isn't the way to go

Comment: NIS is decades old. A simple internet search for "NIS password aging" might help.

Comment: I did the search, NIS does not support Password Aging.

Comment: LDAP  FOR 50+ Users. When i look at Ldap , it looks way to complex n densible only when thete are 100s or 1000s of users